# Find if the input file name is in valid formate(tar.gz) and if it contain all 3 part of the name

Tags: javascript, validation

I got this question from one of the Person:-

A user enters the software name 
in this format  `<project_name>_<team_name>_<release_number>.tar.gz` Like: `OW_XYZ_5.4.tar.gz`

Find if the input file name is in valid formate(tar.gz) and if it contain all 3 part of the name.

Please help me to solve this question using javascript/jquery.

Comment: which three parts? please share the required template that you are looking to validate.

Comment: A user enters the software name 
In this format  <project_name>_<team_name>_<release_number>.tar.gz Like:-
OW_XYZ_5.4.tar.gz.    I have entered this info in the question as well but I don't know why its not displaying there.

Comment: I have shared an answer below, please check and revert.

Comment: Yes It seems really helpful answer. I just want to know about (!!) which you have used !!input.match()  what its exactly meaning of (!!).

Comment: It coerces a value to it Boolean equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that

- *team-name* and *project-name* is **alphanumeric**
- *version-number* is of format **x.x** (*x is one or more digits*)

Use the following regex

```
/^[a-z\d]+_[a-z\d]+_(\d+\.\d+)\.tar.gz$/i
```

**Demo**

```js
var input = "OW_XYZ_5.4.tar.gz";

var isMatch = !!input.match(/^[a-z\d]+_[a-z\d]+_(\d+\.\d+)\.tar.gz$/i);

console.log(isMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = fullfilepath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''); // this is to get only the file name, file upload field gives the full path

 if (!filename.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z\.]*$/)) {
 alert('File name should only containg letters and numbers, please rename image file and upload.');

 }
```